# Loading a list into a NSMutableArray to populate cells of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am building an app which contains a `UITableViewController` with a list of languages. When I click on English for example, it will load up another `UITableViewController` with a list of Videos available on a website for that language. The cells here will differ from clicking on French. So I have a Title and a URL for each video. I'm not keeping the video within the app; the user simply will click on one of the Titles and it will go to the website to play that video.

There are about 1,100 videos, so putting this is code is quite painful. Essentially, from the `prepareForSegue`, I am calling a `UITableViewController` and will display a number of cells depending on how many there are for that language.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.languagesTabTableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    [self.languagesTabTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowingLeafletsAndVideosSegueChinese"])
    {
        LeafletsAndVideosTableViewController *lvtvc = (LeafletsAndVideosTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSMutableArray *availableLeafletsToPass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"3 Facts",@"10 Questions",nil];
        NSMutableArray *availableVideosToPass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
        NSString *theSelectedLanguage = @"Chinese";
        // Calling the set methods on the LeafletsAndVideosTableViewController
        [lvtvc setAvailableLeaflets:availableLeafletsToPass];
        [lvtvc setAvailableVideos:availableVideosToPass];
        [lvtvc setSelectedLanguage:theSelectedLanguage];

    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowingLeafletsAndVideosSegueEnglish"])
    {
        LeafletsAndVideosTableViewController *lvtvc = (LeafletsAndVideosTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSMutableArray *availableLeafletsToPass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"3 Facts",nil];
        NSMutableArray *availableVideosToPass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Video 1",@"Video 2", @"Video 3", @"Video 4", @"Video 5", @"Video 6", nil];
        NSString *theSelectedLanguage = @"English";
        // Calling the set methods on the LeafletsAndVideosTableViewController
        [lvtvc setAvailableLeaflets:availableLeafletsToPass];
        [lvtvc setAvailableVideos:availableVideosToPass];
        [lvtvc setSelectedLanguage:theSelectedLanguage];
    }
```

So `availableVideosToPass` is filled up with "Titles" and as long as it's not nil, it will get shown in the `LeafletsAndVideosTableViewController` without issues. What you're seeing above is just a small subset; the videos have much longer titles and actually spread across 1,100 different videos. That's 1,100 different titles.

I'm quite new to this concept and I don't want to change this code around too much, but is there any way I can load in a file, like a text file, or a spreadsheet of titles? The English selection is always going to have the 1,100 titles, so if I could essentially load in a file into the `NSMutableArray` `availableVideosToPass`.

If this is possible, how would I go about achieving this? I've never done anything like this before so I'm not even sure what to look for online.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: IMO, I will use webservice for such thing....

Comment: Thanks Fahim - that is a good idea, but it just doesn't seem as feasible right now for me. Perhaps something I'll do in the future. Right now, I want to get this app out and work to improve it later, etc.. So although it's more manual, I would love to be able to plug a text file of Titles into a MutableArray and I don't know how this is done.

Comment: this case of manual, I would have used excel that contain all data and using [CONCATENATE()](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excelformulas/18) function, I would have created the NSMutableArray of the point that I need... this way, creating array of even 1000 titles is work of minutes...

Comment: Thanks Fahim - that's really helpful. Please could I ask you to write that out in an answer with an example of how this would look in code, etc?

Comment: you know how to use CONCATENATE? If yes, I will post answer later as answer will be little big...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a simple array and send [writeToFile:] message to it
   (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:).
2. Search for this file by its name/contents. Fill all information by editing this file (it may be in "~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICE-ID}/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/{APPLICATION-ID}/" subfolder) in your favorite editor or even Xcode.
3. Load contents of this file in your application by calling class method of NSArray [arrayWithContentsOfFile:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfFile:).
4. Create a mutable copy of array by invoking method [mutableCopy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/mutableCopy).

    
    More information on file handling is in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9397813/978568)